# Disable terminal commands

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-12.04, rm

I want to disable the use of `rm` except in certain circumstances.  I wrote a function called `remove` in a `.sh` file and it goes though certain checks that I wanted to impose before actually calling `rm`.  However, one could still go into the terminal and simply call the `rm` function rather than using `remove`.  Is there a way to disable the `rm`function except when called by `remove`?  I want it to be as if the `rm` function doesn't "exist" to a user who logs into the terminal, all that "exists" is the remove function.

Maybe even go a step further and when a user calls `rm` it prints to the screen a statement saying to use `remove`.

As a more broad question, is there a way to disable terminal commands except in certain circumstances?  I know I could just make an alias for `rm` to require root, but that's the easy and less convenient way out.

```
#!/bin/bash

function rm {
  if [ $# -le 0 ]; then
    echo "Error: no arguments specified."
  else
    hasDir=0
    for arg in "$@"; do
      if [ -d "$arg" ]; then hasDir=1; fi
    done

    ac="Action canceled."
    resp=("y" "n" "e")

    sure=" "
    while [ "$sure" != "y" ] && [ "$sure" != "n" ]; do
      read -p "PERMANENT ACTION.  Are you sure? (y/n): " sure
    done

    if [ "$sure" == "n" ]; then echo "$ac"; return; fi


    if [ $hasDir -eq 1 ]; then
      direc=" "
      validResp=0
      while [ $validResp -eq 0 ]; do
        read -p "Remove all sub-directories? (y/n/e): " direc
        for ans in "${resp[@]}"; do
          if [ "$direc" == "$ans" ]; then validResp=1; fi
        done
      done

      if [ "$direc" == "e" ]; then echo "$ac"; return; fi
    else
      direc="n"
    fi



    check=" "
    validResp=0
    while [ $validResp -eq 0 ]; do
      read -p "Verify removal of each file? (y/n): " check
      for ans in "${resp[@]}"; do
        if [ "$check" == "$ans" ]; then validResp=1; fi
      done
    done

    if [ "$check" == "e" ]; then echo "$ac"; return; fi


    if [ "$direc" == "n" ]; then
      if [ "$check" == "n" ]; then
        for file in "$@"; do
          if [ ! -d "$file" ]; then command rm -f "$file"; fi
        done
      else 
        for file in "$@"; do
          if [ ! -d "$file" ]; then command rm -i "$file"; fi
        done
      fi
    else
      if [ "$check" == "n" ]; then
        command rm -rf "$@"
      else
        command rm -ir "$@"
      fi
    fi
  fi    
}
```

Comment: I'd worry about all those scripts that you're unaware of that use ``rm`` - from ``cron`` and ``init*`` etc. Could you not just change the PATH to have your ``rm`` first it wouldn't stop people doing ``/bin/rm``though.

Comment: `rm` is an executable, not a shell command or function. Keep in mind that there are other shells besides `bash`. Running `zsh`, for instance, would circumvent any shell-based obstacles you tried to create.

Comment: the issue is I can't name my function `rm`, because it goes into a recursive state.  That's why I have to name it something else, specifically `remove`.

Comment: The reason I want to do this is not for security reasons or anything like that, its more just for the knowledge of being able to do it.  And to keep me from accidentally using `rm` haha.

Comment: While cleaning up the indentation, I noticed you seem to be missing a `fi` in your script.

Comment: where is the missing `fi`?  Everything compiles correctly...

Comment: My mistake; I was going by indentation, and failed to indent one of the `else` clauses properly.

Answer (score 5):

You can override `rm` (or any other command); the `command` built-in lets you access the original command when necessary.

```
rm () {
    # Do something in addition to removing the file

    command rm "$@"
}
```

`command` disables shell function look-up.

Comment: I added my code in the original post.  When I add `command` I get the error message "rm: missing operand"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture all uses of `rm`, then there is one way. However, I must mention that it's a dirty, not-recommended way.

```
mv /bin/rm /bin/rm.bak
cp my_rm_script /bin/rm
```

my_rm_script should contain call to /bin/rm.bak, instead of /bin/rm.

This will capture all calls to command `rm`.

However, this will not work on busybox type architecture, where the NAME of the binary also matters.

Comment: this sounds way dirty to me.  not sure if I should be changing things like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dpkg-divert`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/en/man8/dpkg-divert.8.html) to install a different `rm` on your system.

See also this article [Replacing binaries with dpkg-divert](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/118) for an example using a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, its a bit weird way but works exactly the way you want.

create a `directory` in your home folder

`$~ mkdir ~/myrm`

`$~ cd ~/myrm`

create a symbolic link `rm` to your `remove` binary

`$~ ln -s /path/to/remove rm`

Now the above command will create a link `rm` which points to `remove` basically you are invoking `remove` by calling `rm`. Make sure that executable permission is given on `rm` else use

`$~ chmod 0777 rm`

Now its time to put the path in the `$PATH` variable.

`$~ PATH=~/myrm/:$PATH`

make sure that its `~/myrm:$PATH` not `$PATH:myrm`. So now whenever you call `rm` it will search for `rm` in `~/myrm` directory and invoke it.

Comment: chmod `0777` is very bad advice! This allows *anyone* to modify your script. If you want to make it executable, use `chmod a+x rm` instead.

Comment: ya 0777 is a bad idea. 0644 would be perfect here..